# Cannot fetch different tags for the same questionid

Tags: java, list, hibernate, web-applications, tuples

Im trying to fetch tags of a particular questionId which is stored in the database,
The problem is ,it is displaying one tag name instead of different tags.(for questionId:5010 it has 2 tags java and Php and below that question it is displaying only java twice)

```
    public class TagDAOImpl implements TagDAO {
    public List<String> viewQuestion(String question) throws Exception {
        List<String> quesString = null;
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        Session session = null;

        try {
            quesString = new ArrayList<String>();
            sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            QuestionEntity tag = new QuestionEntity();
            // Question q=new Question();
            // q.setTagId(question);
            // ques.setQuestionString(question.getQuestionString());
            System.out.println("dao" + question);

            // session.persist(ques);

            session.getTransaction().begin();

            Query query = session
                    .createQuery("from QuestionEntity where tagId=?");
            query.setString(0, question);
            List<QuestionEntity> custList = query.list();

            List list = query.list();
            for (QuestionEntity tagEntity : custList) {
                System.out
                        .println("Question ID=>" + tagEntity.getQuestionId()
                                + "\nQuestion String=>"
                                + tagEntity.getQuestionString());
                List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
                newList.addAll(getTag(tagEntity.getQuestionId()));

                quesString.add(tagEntity.getQuestionString());
                quesString.addAll(newList);

            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (HibernateException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
            logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
            throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
            logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
            throw exception;
        } finally {
            if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return quesString;
    }

    // quesString.add();

    // quesString.add("\n");

    public List<String> getTag(int question) throws Exception {
        List<String> quesString = null;
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        Session session = null;

        try {
            quesString = new ArrayList<String>();
            sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            QuestionEntity tag = new QuestionEntity();
            // Question q=new Question();
            // q.setTagId(question);
            // ques.setQuestionString(question.getQuestionString());
            System.out.println("dao" + question);

            // session.persist(ques);

            session.getTransaction().begin();

            Query query2 = session
                    .createQuery("from QuestionEntity where questionId=?");
            query2.setInteger(0, question);
            List<QuestionEntity> tagList = query2.list();
            for (QuestionEntity tagEntity : tagList)
                System.out.println("custlist " + tagEntity.getTagId());

            // List list = query2.list();
            for (QuestionEntity tagEntity : tagList) {
                System.out.println("Question ID=>" + tagEntity.getQuestionId()
                        + "\nQuestion String=>" + tagEntity.getQuestionString()
                        + "\ntagId=>" + tagEntity.getTagId());
                quesString.add(tagEntity.getTagId());
                System.out.println(tagEntity.getTagId());

            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            // quesString.add();

            // quesString.add("\n");

        } catch (HibernateException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
            logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
            throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
            logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
            throw exception;
        } finally {
            if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return quesString;
    }

}
```

it is displaying two same tags for one question id.
I need to get Java and Php as tags for questionid 5010.
in table script it is working fine but in DAO functions its not working properly.
[image]

Questionid and tagid are composite primary key.

> INSERT INTO Question VALUES(DBquestionId.NEXTVAL,'U1','What is java and javascript?','Java');
>   INSERT INTO Question VALUES(DBquestionId.NEXTVAL,'U1','What is java and javascript?','Java Script');
>   INSERT INTO Question VALUES(DBquestionId.NEXTVAL,'U1','What is java and javascript?','Python');
>   INSERT INTO Question VALUES(DBquestionId.NEXTVAL,'U1','Who is python?','Python');
>   INSERT INTO Question VALUES(DBquestionId.NEXTVAL,'U1','What is HTML?','HTML');
>   INSERT INTO Question VALUES(DBquestionId.NEXTVAL,'U1','What is java?','Java');
>   INSERT INTO Question VALUES(DBquestionId.NEXTVAL,'U1','What is teh differeence between post and get?','Java Script');
>   INSERT INTO Question VALUES(DBquestionId.NEXTVAL,'U1','What is static variable in java?','Java');
>   INSERT INTO Question VALUES(DBquestionId.NEXTVAL,'U1','can i call/refer groovy static inner class in Java','Java');
>   INSERT INTO Question VALUES(DBquestionId.NEXTVAL,'U1','How to create executable JAR file for Swing on eclipse that runs without eclipse','Java');
>   INSERT INTO Question VALUES('5010','U1','How to create executable JAR file for Swing on eclipse that runs without eclipse','Php');

Comment: Can you share QuestionEntity class source code/

Comment: "@Entity
@Table(name = "Question")
@GenericGenerator(name = "generatorName", strategy = "sequence", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "DBquestionId") })
public class QuestionEntity {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "generatorName")
 private Integer questionId;
 private String userId;
 private Integer upvotes;
 private Integer downvotes;
 private String questionString;
 private String tagId;"